# Protractor with Firefox (32 latest) browser not loading

Tags: javascript, firefox, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

So for some reason, when I run protractor, Firefox (32 latest) just opens with an empty browser and doesn't navigate to the baseURL. The tests I have written work fine with chrome, but not with firefox. It probably has something to do with the way the conf file is set up. Any ideas?

Conf file:

```
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

    specs: [
        'e2e/*.js'
    ],

    multiCapabilities: [
       {
            'browserName': 'firefox'
        },
        {
            'browserName': 'chrome'
        }
    ],

    chromeOnly: false,

    chromeDriver: 'e2e/chromedriver/',

    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',

    framework: 'jasmine',

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firefox 32 is broken with selenium <= 2.42.2

**UPDATE** Selenium 2.43 is out!

Need [selenium 2.43](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.43/) or newer version. Or downgrade Firefox back to version 31 or less.

Issue: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7642

FYI output might look like this:

```
Using the selenium server at: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

/home/username/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:109
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
003407891246748webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com
1409877425492   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: /tmp/anonymous7362003407891246748webdriver-profile/extensions/webdriver-staging
1409877425492   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1409877425502   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Directory state JSON differs:........
```

Comment: Thanks man. That was indeed the issue. I just downgraded and it seems to at least run the tests (even though there are some clicking problems).

Comment: Any idea why my tests pass in chrome, but display something like:
Stacktrace:
     ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
 for firefox? The elements don't seem to be getting clicked properly.

Comment: You should open a separate question for that issue, please include some html and the test code ;)

Comment: Thanks but I figured it out. Firefox didn't like the way I was clicking a drop down. So I changed it to element(by.linkText('')).click()

Comment: It might also help to point out that grunt-protractor-runner is outdated at this time (https://github.com/teerapap/grunt-protractor-runner/issues/88) so you will have the same problem even if you have the latest version of protractor and webdriver-manager. What I did for now is skipped using grunt-protractor-runner and I just use protractor directly.