# Cannot get protractor to run Firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have tried many versions of Firefox, but can’t get protractor to run them. I have followed the [installation steps](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial) on their site and I downgraded to Firefox 31.0.

Currently it will begin properly, then swap the app icon in the dock 2x then do nothing, not even open a browser window. After aprox. one minute and then it will timeout and quit.

The first line hangs, lines two and after came about a minute later.

```
$ protractor conf.js
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
The last active task was:
WebDriver.createSession()
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
FF
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
kipping unavailable install location app-system-share
1414172895384 addons.xpi  DEBUG Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: /var/folders/55/rcwf6nxx41nctw5qgtln0zqw0000gn/T/anonymous999359446682165432webdriver-profile/extensions/webdriver-staging
1414172895398 addons.xpi  DEBUG checkForChanges
1414172895404 addons.xpi  DEBUG Directory state JSON differs: cache [] state [{"name":"app-system-local","addons":{"web2pdfextension@web2pdf.adobedotcom":{"descriptor":"/Library/Application Support/Mozilla/Extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/web2pdfextension@web2pdf.adobedotcom","mtime":1411008686000,"rdfTime":1348459481000}}},{"name":"app-global","addons":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"descriptor":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","mtime":1405567571000,"rdfTime":1405565774000}}},{"name":"app-profile","addons":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"descriptor":"/var/folders/55/rcwf6nxx41nctw5qgtln0zqw0000gn/T/anonymous999359446682165432webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com","mtime":1414172895000,"rdfTime":1414172895000}}}]
1414172895408 addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG Opening XPI database /var/folders/55/rcwf6nxx41nctw5qgtln0zqw0000gn/T/anonymous999359446682165432webdriver-profile/extensions.json
1414172895409 addons.xpi  DEBUG New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1414172895423 addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible
1414172895424 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Save changes
1414172895424 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Save changes
1414172895424 addons.xpi  DEBUG New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
1414172895426 addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
1414172895426 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Save changes
1414172895426 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Save changes
1414172895426 addons.xpi  DEBUG New add-on web2pdfextension@web2pdf.adobedotcom installed in app-system-local
1414172895428 addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG Make addon app-system-local:web2pdfextension@web2pdf.adobedotcom visible
1414172895429 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Save changes
1414172895429 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Save changes
1414172895432 addons.xpi  DEBUG Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1414172895432 addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG Updating add-on states
1414172895433 addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG Writing add-ons list
1414172895513 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Starting timer
1414172895529 addons.manager  DEBUG shutdown
1414172895529 addons.xpi  DEBUG shutdown
1414172895529 addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG shutdown
1414172895530 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Flush called while data is dirty
1414172895538 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Starting write
1414172895593 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Write succeeded
1414172895593 addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 16
1414172895593 addons.xpi  DEBUG Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1414172895595 addons.manager  DEBUG Async provider shutdown done
1414172895795 addons.manager  DEBUG Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1414172895797 addons.manager  DEBUG Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1414172895798 addons.xpi  DEBUG startup
1414172895799 addons.xpi  DEBUG Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
1414172895800 addons.xpi  DEBUG Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: /var/folders/55/rcwf6nxx41nctw5qgtln0zqw0000gn/T/anonymous999359446682165432webdriver-profile/extensions/webdriver-staging
1414172895814 addons.xpi  DEBUG checkForChanges
1414172895820 addons.xpi  DEBUG No changes found
1414172895906 addons.manager  DEBUG shutdown
1414172895906 addons.xpi  DEBUG shutdown
1414172895906 addons.xpi  DEBUG Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1414172895912 addons.manager  DEBUG Async provider shutdown done

    at new bot.Error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/response.js:106:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:151:24
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1640:20)
    at notify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:444:12)
    at notifyAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:422:7)
    at resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:400:7)
    at fulfill (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:512:5)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1640:20)
    at notify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:444:12)
    at notifyAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:422:7)
    at resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:400:7)
    at [object Object].fulfill (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:512:5)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:703:49
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/http/http.js:96:5
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:131:7)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
==== async task ====
WebDriver.navigate().to(data:text/html,<html></html>)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:302:15)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.Navigation.to (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:969:23)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:661:26)
    at [object Object].Protractor.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:1221:15)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/kirkstrobeck/git/tipfortip/www/public/index-spec.js:14:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd/index.js:94:14
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1640:20)
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1505:8)
    at [object Object].wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:252:14)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
==== async task ====
Asynchronous test function: it()
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd/index.js:93:33)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/async-callback.js:45:37)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:17)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:2162:8)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Spec.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:2503:14)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)
    at onComplete (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:2205:18)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Spec.finish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:2477:5)
    at [object Object].onComplete (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:2504:10)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:2219:14)
    at [object Object]._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:2199:18)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)==== async task ====
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/kirkstrobeck/git/tipfortip/www/public/index-spec.js:13:3)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)
    at describe (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kirkstrobeck/git/tipfortip/www/public/index-spec.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.exports.executeSpecs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/index.js:130:7)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/frameworks/jasmine.js:49:12
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
$
```

Comment: Which version of protractor are you using? There was a breaking change in Firefox 32 that required  a fix into FirefoxDriver (selenium) and Protractor [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25676602). I think you might need to downgrade protractor to run on Firefox 31.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you encounter this issue in 2016, try updating Firefox to the latest, precisely to

> Firefox v47.0.1

and your protractor tests should run again; no need to go to an older versions a**s of today, 07/28/2016 :)**

Also note that Firefox comes prepackaged with the selenium server jar so you don't need to declare an explicit driver for it as you do with chrome, so in your protractor configuration file, 
just declare browser name like below and it should work:

```
 capabilities: {
   'browserName': 'firefox'   
 },
```